# How can I Keep Cows from Running Away?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've built a fenced area in Minecraft in which cows, pigs and over wildlife I intend to congregate.  Only problem, how can I make them happy?  In that they quite often bounce by the fence, wanting to get out.  Any recommendations?
[image]

Comment: I approve of this question

Comment: @CruelCrow I approve of you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Cows (along with all passive mobs) have no AI other than "wander". They will blissfully stumble head-first into lava if given the chance.

As of Beta 1.6.6, there is no way to encourage Passive Mobs to stick around; even "happy" cows will disappear into the ether if you wander far enough away that the chunk gets unloaded from Memory.

On the other hand, fence-escaping can simply be halted by making the fence taller.

**Edit:**

As of Beta 1.8, passive mobs no longer despawn. If you fence a cow, sheep, or pig, *and* keep them safe from wolves / aggressive mobs, they should stay fenced-in indefinitely.

Comment: I was hoping to create a massive field full of cows and pigs, then make friends with a wolf and let them go crazy!

Comment: @Wonea - However, Wolves won't attack passive mobs unless you attack them first.

Comment: If mass murder is your objective, I'd recommend using TooManyItems to spawn in a load of pig spawners. You can quickly amass hundreds of pigs this way. Also, much more efficient than wolves: TNT.

Comment: Can fences *themselves* be made taller? Or do you mean using other blocks (as in the dirt blocks pictured)?

Comment: @Cyclops - I think as of 1.8 you can place blocks directly on top of fences. Alternatively, the pre 1.8 way of making fences is by starting from the top - place a row of fence blocks at the highest altitude you want, then dig out the blocks underneath them, putting another fence in the vacated space. Continue until you have a fence of the desired length.

Answer (score 7):

You can prevent the cows bouncing by simply making the fence taller. Their pathing AI seems to think they can make what should be a one block jump; however, the fences' unusual collision check ends up blocking them. Thus, they start bouncing whenever they wander near.

You can't make them stay though, they will despawn eventually (as of 1.6.6).

Comment: Is there a bug assigned to fixing this, couldn't seem to find anything. https://mojang.atlassian.net/browse/MC